# Align the SQL server Query results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
select '(''{' + cast(UniqueId as varchar(MAX)) + '}'',''' + [Name] + ''',''' + Address+ '''),'
from testTable;
```

the above query gives me the below results

```
('{C7F93C19-327E-47C1-B4A8-C397FF82D7C8}','name1','Address111'),
('{A686D54D-C742-4677-899A-AEFC39440615}','This is a long name','Address2'),
('{7DEF4222-1192-4DCA-934F-208D49FCE3E5}','This is a very loooooooooong name','Address 3'),
```

How shall i format the results to achieve like the below results. that is align the third coloumn by saving some space after the second coloumn

```
('{C7F93C19-327E-47C1-B4A8-C397FF82D7C8}','name1',                                'Address111'),
('{A686D54D-C742-4677-899A-AEFC39440615}','This is a long name',                  'Address2'),
('{7DEF4222-1192-4DCA-934F-208D49FCE3E5}','This is a very loooooooooong name',    'Address 3'),
```

Comment: This should *really* be handled at the application layer...

Comment: I am trying to create a post deployment script  which needs to be formatted as specified to pass code review :(

Comment: Then let the script do the formatting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query helped me to do the formatting

```
DECLARE @MaxKeyLength INT = (SELECT MAX(LEN([Name])) FROM testTable)


select '(''{' + cast(UniqueId as varchar(MAX)) + '}'',''' + LEFT(LTRIM([Name]) + ''',                                             ', @MaxKeyLength + 4) + ''''  + Address+ '''),'
from testTable;
```

Comment: Take a look at the Stuff function in SQL, too...it can be handy. I was writing an answer when you posted this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what SQL is intended for, even though it somehow seems to work.

SQL shall deliver the raw data, formatting is task of the application. This could be e. g. a PHP page inserting the data into a HTML table or a GUI application, written in C++, Java, C#, ... presenting the data appropriately.

So your query would simply look like this:

```
SELECT cast(UniqueId as varchar(MAX)), [Name], Address FROM testTable
```

If it was a simple C console application, you could iterate over all results, getting the maximal length for each column and then output the data, iterating over it again:

```
printf(
    "%s, %-*s, %-*s\n",
    currentId,
    maxLenName, currentName,
    maxLenAddress, currentAddress
);
```

Edit: You could query the lengths, too:

```
SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH([Name])), MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(Address)) FROM testTable
```

Then you need to iterate over the data only once.

Comment: i was able to format as the answer which i have posted